# Drupal: How is this component named?

Tags: drupal-7

I would like to create a table that looks/behaves like the one to manage fields when editing content types.

[image: screenshot]

How is this one named? Is this form API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the drag and drop sorting behavior, then you should look at the documentation for [`drupal_add_tabledrag`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7).

And perhaps this tutorial might help: http://aswapathy.com/d78tu/tabledrag/theme_the_form_doc

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it using Forms API together with a table.
If you are new to forms API, this step by step introduction is really good:
http://drupal.org/node/262422